# iPhone custom url scheme Add shortcut to homescreen

Tags: iphone, url-scheme

I have found this site http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen which has javascript for showing a bubble to encourage the user in Safari to create a shortcut to the web page, but I was wondering if anyone has a way to swap the web page url with the native app custom url scheme before creating the shortcut.

Comment: So, you want to make a web clip icon on the home screen that when launched, opens a native app? Seems like a useless step, unless I'm missing something, because why wouldn't the user just launch the app they want to open?

Comment: I know I can call my app from a web page with a custom url scheme, but if I wanted to have different entry points into the app based upon parameters set in the web page before adding the shortcut or webclip with url scheme on the homescreen, then users could click on the shortcut to execute the functionality without going back to the web page or going through the app.

Comment: As a user, I would hate you for making me clutter up my device with a bunch of entry points to the same application. Sounds like you need to clean up your UX a little bit if you need to devise a way to get to a specific portion of your app like that.

Comment: A late comment for anyone arriving here by Google, as I did: Yes. The above commenters are missing something. Custom URL schemes allow you to open apps with specific documents, or even with content retrieved from a server. For instance, a custom springboard web clip allows users to directly open server-based FileMaker Go databases without having to first open the FileMaker Go app and manually navigate - a handy solution for less technical users that I have repeatedly seen requested in real world use.

Answer (score 2):

In some situations it can be helpful to have a few shortcuts to start an app from a custom URL with different parameters. For example if you have an application that is a container for a few little applications. So, to start one of such little apps directly. without a menu you can use a custom URL with the app name as a parameter.

I spent some time trying to find the solutions. I found to ways:

1. [This link](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/custom-icons-on-iphone-5-no-jb.390612/) explains how to make a custom url shortcut saving it from Safari using a special html file prepared. This method relies on the html page refresh to a custom URL, and requires an internet connection. A side effect - when you start the app from a shortcut you shortly see Safari opening the html page before your app starts.
2. And [this link](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/custom-icons-without-jailbreak-or-internet.391089/) explains how to do that with the iPhone Configuration Utility. This approach requires an installation of configuration profile on you device. A side effect of this method what I see is - after you start your application from a shortcut you see two applications in the background - your app, and the Web clip (the shortcut).

Comment: Thanks Sergey for your work and response. I was able to get this to work using a cookie and some trickery, all of which would not be allowed by iTunes. The functionality offered in Android just creates the icon from within the App and that is what is really needed here. I think Facebook uses it in the implementation of their new Home product and why it was not done for iPhone. However, I can certainly understand how this could be abused

Comment: -1. Linking to solutions instead of explicitly giving the answer leaves later users stranded when the URLs change, as they have in this case.