# In iOS, is there a way to open the same app from multiple shortcuts(icons) by passing different arguments to the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to know whether something like this is possible.
I need to have 4 apps. 95% of the content of all 4 apps will be shown inside WebViews where remote websites will be opened, so I don't want to create 4 different apps, instead I would like to have 4 different icons in the homescreen which can open the same application by passing different arguments.

Suggestions/Alternatives/Hacks are welcome!!

Note: Distribution of the app/apps will not be via Apple App Store.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible by using custom URL shortcuts on the home screen. This may require jailbreaking. See info at bottom of page [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html), and a tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723188/iphone-custom-url-scheme-add-shortcut-to-homescreen) is related, but doesn't have any good answers. It raises the concern that users might not want their home screen cluttered with four icons for one app or one set of related things.

See also this project, which apparently doesn't work any more but may have some hints:

http://lifehacker.com/5859499/icon-project-creates-quick-ios-home-screen-shortcuts-to-contacts-settings-and-more